# How to retreive all facets?

Tags: java, algolia

I'm using traditional JEE application with algolia, and I need to retrieve all values of a facet (which are around 250) and all I get is up to 100.
According to the documentation I can't request more than 100 ([algolia doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/maxFacetHits/)).
How can I do it?
P.S. I don't want to use the "write" API key, only the safe one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to go over the 100 limit using `maxFacetHits`.

A solution could be to browse the entire index to get all the possible values of a facet. Of course it can take some time depending on your index size, and we don't recommend doing this to display it real time.
You will probably want to cache the result, and update it from time to time.

Also, if you records are also stored in a database, it may be easier to retrieve this list of facet values from it rather than using Algolia.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, in thus case I had to fill the query with the following attributes.

```
    query.setHitsPerPage(10);
    query.setPage(0);
    query.setAnalytics(false);
    query.setAttributesToRetrieve(Arrays.asList("*"));
    query.setFacets("category");
```

Then I can do a search and request the facets with `getFacets()`.